# Curl request doesn't work as same request in Postman

Tags: php, curl, web, postman

Hello Im trying to make some automation in social network. I logged in with curl with success, but Im stuck on another actions.

The thing is Im sending POST request with cookies after login and parameters parsed from html form to form action url and Curl returns http code 200 on this request but it should return 302 (I tried FOLLOWLOCATION false).

I retrieved all data from curl request and tried to send it via POSTMAN app for linux. And it works. I don't understand why it doesn't work with curl.

```
public function requestPost($url, array $postData)
{
    $this->setRequest($url);
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
    return curl_exec($this->curlResource);
}

/**
 * Common function for Post/Get setup.
 *
 * @param string $url
 *   Url to send request to.
 */
private function setRequest($url)
{
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, self::USER_AGENT);
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Save cookies in memory until curl_close  is not called. Windows use NULL.
 //        curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '\\' === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ? NULL : '/dev/null');

    $tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $tmpfname);
    curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);

    // Set proxy settings.
    if ($this->proxy)
    {
        list($proxyType, $proxyIp, $proxyPort, $proxyLogin, $proxyPass) = explode(":", $this->proxy);
        curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyIp);
        curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxyPort);
        curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, $proxyType == 'http' ? CURLPROXY_HTTP : CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
        curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME, $proxyLogin);
        curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD, $proxyPass);
        curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($this->curlResource, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    }
}
```

Same code has been used for login operation.

Comment: Have you tried curl_getinfo() or curl_error() functions of php?

Comment: Yep. curl_error returns empty string. Curl info returns code 302 for login operation as it should. But for the request Im trying to do it returns 200. Actually I get all information (cookie, headers) for postman from curl_getinfo.

Comment: I am not to deep into curl, but you get a 302 response code. So something is redirected. Try CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = true (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html)

Comment: Sorry maybe I've been not too clear. I don't get 302 redirect.
I'm writing some kind of Bot, first I logged in and curl works (302 redirect returned)! But then I need to do another request for another operation. And it doesn't work. It returns code 200 for it but should return 302.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a few days with this I came to a conclusion that the problem was not in differences betwee curl and postman. As I tried to send curl request with predefined cookies, post data and it works.

At the end

> html_entity_decode()

saved my day. Url that has been setted for curl contained &.amp; special char instead of & and that was the cause of the trouble.